# Accessing a method of a Json object in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I was doing debug related to certain portion of my code wasn't able to hit Google's API from my local machine, however the same code works fine when deployed on a server.
Looking at node-modules implementation of at Google's here, I have a question: [Google's API request file](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-googleapis-common/blob/main/src/apirequest.ts)

In the above file `authClient` is defined like this:

```
let authClient = params.auth || options.auth;
```

So `authClient` becomes a json object here and later in the code Google accesses a method of it:

```
if (authClient && typeof authClient === 'object') {
    if (options.http2) {
      const authHeaders = await authClient.getRequestHeaders(options.url);
```

So I wondered how they sort of deserialized a Json object to be able to access `getRequestHeaders` method?

Comment: `So authClient becomes a json object` why do you think that it should/will get a string with JSON encoded data? `So I wondered how they sort of deserialized a Json object` The if condition checks if `authClient` is of the type `object` (a JavaScript Object) and not a string containing JSON encoded data.

Comment: I printed it. Here is what I got for `authClient`  https://pastebin.com/B7isz3fP

Comment: And what do you want to say with this pastbin. That could be a JavaScript object or JSON.

Comment: Oops sorry, now that I am tracing I seem to be understanding the point! Let me confirm it soon if my understanding is clear now.